# Rails Friendly ID Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application using FriendlyID. I currently have two models, cats and services which I would like to turn from this:

```
/cats/some-category
/services/a-service
```

into:

```
/some-category
/a-service
```

I currently have routing for each like this:

```
resources :cats
resources :services
```

I want to KEEP the admin functionality the same on the back-end and ONLY change the routes on the front-end.

I've tried using ...

```
:path => ''
```

... but it messes up the back-end routing in the admin.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want such route, it's difficult to identify which object to fetch.

Answer (score 2):

the main reason why you can't turn

```
/cats/some-category
/services/a-service
```

into

```
/some-category
/a-service
```

is due to some clear routing issues. The your biggest problem is of course the fact that cats and services are both handled by different controllers and there is no way to mash both controllers under one route.

if you want to make this work, you should make a new controller first, say `FriendlyController`

FriendlyController

```
FriendlyController < ApplicationController do
  before_action :set_object

  def set_object
    @object = Service.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Cats.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

and in your `routes.rb` do something like this

```
get '/:id' => 'friendly#index'
```

---

Though while this would work, do note why this is a bad idea from a long term perspective.

1. first of, this would cause a lot of possible route conflicts later on once the project grows as rails wouldn't be able properly evaluate which route to pick on certain occasions.
2. how will you handle cats and services with the same friendly id?

---

If you really want to put the emphasis on the friendly ID instead of the controller, you can just shorten the urls like so

```
resources :cats, as: 'c'
```